# Heigth não obedece o valor informado em porcentagem

Tags: html, css

Queria saber o motivo da propriedade height no css não obedecer o valor dado em % mas obedecer o valor dado em px, em % é como se só o width funcionasse, alguém pode me explicar por que isso acontece e como contornar esse problema usando %?

código que eu estava fazendo, notem que na 1° div eu defini a altura maior que a largura em px e ela obedeceu as proporções, mas quando usei uma altura maior em % ela foi ignorada.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        #vermelho{
            background-color: red;
            width: 300px;
            height:1000px;
        }
        #amarelo{
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100% ;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="vermelho"> </div>
        <div id="amarelo">
            <p>ewqeqwewqeq </p>
        </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando se usa %, o elemento em questão busca se basear no tamanho de um elemento "pai", que no caso seria o `<body>`. Tente adicionar isso:

```
html,body{
  height: 100%
}
```

Comment: então o body ,por padrão, não vem com 100% de height mais sim 100% de width?

Comment: @Akali Creio que sim, o height do navegador precisa da definição do desenvolvedor para saber a quantidade de altura que ele precisa. Em muitos casos não se usa isso, porque a medida em que você vai colocando conteúdo dentro do <body>, ele vai aumentando essa altura, então no fim acabam não precisando usar.